# Is it my imagination, or are we getting a lot of new users?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed many 1- and 101-rep users contributing a lot of good comments and also some good questions and answers lately.  (See, for example, [What are the dangers of walking barefoot in towns/cities?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/15701/what-are-the-dangers-of-walking-barefoot-in-towns-cities)).  Is this correct?  Any theories as to why this is so?  Has this happened before, and if so, do these new users stick or do they wander off?

Answer (score 9):

So I ran this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/outdoors/query/18206/total-number-of-registered-users-over-time) which shows the number of registered users over time and it looks like the rate of increase has actually slacked off some.

[image]

The Y axis is the number of users and the X is the number of months.

Some more statistics,

- 7.4% of users have over 200 rep
- 1.03% of users have over 2000 rep
- 0.77% of users have over 3000 rep
- The top 10 most active users wrote 890 questions and 1684 answers for **26% of the questions** and **20% of the answers**.
- In this month so far there has been approximately 6400 votes, **17%** of that has come from the top **2 voters** this month and the **top 4** have contributed **21%** of the votes.

The point I am trying to make with those statistics is that a great deal of the activity is being driven by a very small amount of users. So I don't think that there is a real uptick in usage from newer users.

As for why you are seeing a lot of activity from new users on that question is because it hit the Hot Questions and it's one of those questions where everyone has an opinion.

Comment: So the top 4 voters each voted an average of 336 times so far in March 2017?  That's an average of 12.4 times a day.  This is amazing! I thought I voted a lot, but I've averaged only 80 votes a month since I joined.  What we can tentatively conclude is that of the 47 new users this month, zero to two will continue on to get a rep of 2,000 or more.  (1% of 47 = 0.5; I'm going up to 2 to be generous in the error bar.)

Comment: @ab2 See my edits because the voting is much more lopsided when you only count the top 2 users.

Comment: Wow! That's an average of 20 votes per day so far in March 2017 (counting today, March 27) by the top two voters.  I would not have guessed there were an average of 20 (Qs plus As) per day.

Comment: @ab2 They are probably drifting through the related questions lists voting on older posts. I'll do that some times.

Comment: I think your graph shows the rate of increase has actually *increased* (not slacked off) in the last 30 months.

Comment: @MartinF It depends on what you count as recent. In the last month or slow it seems to have slacked off some